# Android Jelly Bean service that receives all touch events

Tags: android, service, accessibility, android-4.2-jelly-bean, touch-event

I am an undergraduate research assistant working on an android accessibility project. My task involves collecting as much data about the user experience as possible, including touch events and other view interactions. I require 2 services: an accessibility service to gather details about the view current interaction, and a `TouchListener` service that is able to intercept `MotionEvents`.

My problem is with the `TouchListener` service. Is there any known way to intercept all touch events and pass them on to the current view?

Essentially, it seems like an invisible system-overlay view is needed to constantly listen for touch events, but the view can either intercept all touch events and NOT pass them to the view behind, or it can pass the even back and register the touch event as an ambiguous `ACTION_OUTSIDE` event, giving no details about the interaction.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085022/android-overlay-to-grab-all-touch-and-pass-them-on?lq=1), and the obstacle is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656185/type-system-overlay-in-ics). If anyone has found a work-around, please post!