# Android Accessibility - Edit all touch events

Tags: android, touch, accessibility

I am building an accessibility related service. 
My goal is to catch all touch-events, change the event's parameters (i.e. event.x = event.getX()+5) and pass it on to the current running application (any application).

After trying to use a system-overlay (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156556/android-use-system-overlay-to-change-touch-events/29156940?iemail=1&noredirect=1#29156940)), I understood that this is pretty much impossible for Android > 4.0 for security reasons, and was wandering if there any way to use the [AccessibilityEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) or any other accessibility-related method.

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible on any version of Android unless you are using a rooted device or you modify the framework.

Comment: @alanv - Thank you. Can you please give more details? Using a rooted device is an option (if no other option...).